# Facebook app canvas fbml loading blank page

Tags: facebook, fbml

I developed a facebook app with `fbml` canvas.

Sometimes for me it loads a blank page (say 1/10 times). For a user in another location it is always loading blank page.

Is it a problem with facebook or my hosting?

Please help me out to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It most likely is on the facebook site. If it was a fault on your side, it would always have come as blank. Sometimes facebook servers go down, and you see blank pages. I have developed a number of facebook applications and unfortunately this problem happens with those apps just as well. So don't worry, it is there with the facebook itself.